# How to splite Trial c#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online

hi i want to get just the Crm and the number in the line
tenx

```
string emailsubject = "Email Test 2 CRM:0276002";

public string GetCrmSubjectNum()
{
    string final = //;

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Do you always have this kind of format? So always "CRM:*" t the end of a string where you want the number after `CRM:`? There are many different ways of how to solve this, so can you please add more examples on how your string could look like?

Comment: yes i have this number after the crm i need the num by function in c# that bring my string answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little bit unclear what you want.
If you always have "CRM" in the subject, then you could do it like following:

```
using System;

   namespace ConsoleApplication1
   {
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string emailsubject = "Email Test 2 CRM:0276002";

            emailsubject = GetCrmSubjectNum(emailsubject);

            Console.WriteLine(emailsubject);

            Console.Read();
        }



        public static string GetCrmSubjectNum(string emailsubject)
        {
           emailsubject = emailsubject.Remove(0, emailsubject.IndexOf("CRM"));

            return emailsubject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just need the number you could do: emailsubject = emailsubject.Remove(0, emailsubject.IndexOf("CRM") + 4);

Comment: sorry man but i need the crm to
tenx

Answer (score 0):

I would go with this, because Substring() is the fastest way:

```
public string GetCrmSubjectNum(string emailSubject)
{
    return emailSubject.Substring(emailSubject.IndexOf("CRM:", StringComparison.Ordinal) + "CRM:".Length);
}
```